How to change texture from animation player in godot
I have a player and an animation where he hold a plate of food all set up in the animation player. I want to be able to change the plate of food to different ones like a meat plate or a veggie plate for example. Is there a way to do this without having to create separate new animations with all the different plates ? Like applying the currect texture before the animation starts playing and being able to change through multiple plates of food ?


The way i have it set up rn, i can only show one plate i have a holding plate idle animation. How can i accomodate both textures shown bellow in the same holding plate idle animation ? Or would i have to make 2 different ones holding plate meat and carrot/holding plate meat ?

You could accomplish this by applying all the animations to a Sprite that displays the plate, and then have a different Sprite node that is a child of the plate which you can use to set the texture of the current food to.
The scene for this would look like:
[Sprite2D] Plate <- Add animations to this node.
    [Sprite2D] FoodItem <- Set food textures.

This would allow every food item to use the same animations!
